# How to solve no-underscore-dangle error without making the error off in config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

In my app, I had to add the following part `e._targetInst.child.memoizedProps[0]` but is giving esLint error **no-underscore-dangle** and I would like to solve it without disabling the error config.

The code where this is applied

```
const handleSelectSite = ({ onChange: onChangeSelectSite }) => {
            return e => {
              setOnFieldChangeConfirm(() => () =>
                onChangeSelectSite('siteId', e.target.value),
              );
              console.log(e._targetInst.child.memoizedProps[0]);
              setConfirmMsg(
                `${formatMessage(messages.confirmChangeMessage, {
                  previous: candidateSite,
                  newValue: e._targetInst.child.memoizedProps[0],
                })}`,
              );
              setConfirmDialog(true);
            };
          };
```

Comment: You can change the code to *not* have dangling underscores in identifiers, or `// eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle` the two occurrences to "ignore" them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either ignore the linter error using `// eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle` or by destructuring and renaming:

```
const handleSelectSite = ({ onChange: onChangeSelectSite }) => {
  return e => {
    setOnFieldChangeConfirm(() => () =>
      onChangeSelectSite('siteId', e.target.value),
    );

    const { _targetInst: targetInst } = e;

    setConfirmMsg(
      `${formatMessage(messages.confirmChangeMessage, {
        previous: candidateSite,
        newValue: targetInst.child.memoizedProps[0],
      })}`,
    );
    setConfirmDialog(true);
  };
};
```